# Can a South Korean citizen visiting Canada travel to the United States?

Tags: visas, international-travel, esta

My friend from South Korea is visiting me in Canada (she is not a Canadian citizen). Is it possible for her to get an ESTA (Electronic System for Travel Authorization) while in Canada, and then visit the U.S. with me by driving across the border?

Comment: @GregHewgill The page you cite seems to deal with baggage forwarding, and not the subject matter of the original question.

Comment: @David: I haven't a clue how that happened, obviously that's wrong. I'll delete the comment but I don't know where my vote went to. This question is clearly a duplicate of the question linked in my remaining comment.

Comment: @GregHewgill Don't feel bad: I just deleted the entirety of one of my Answers!